# Windows Remote Desktop protocol error

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

So, related to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/224434/realvnc-command-line-switches), I am now also trying to integrate Windows Remote Desktop for certain other boxes that my app's users will have to remote into. I have a known good remote box and can connect through the user interface, but when I try to connect from the command line I get a message: "Because of a protocol error detected at the client (code 0x1104), this session will be disconnected. Please try connecting to the remote computer again."

I looked at the command-line switches, and there doesn't seem to be anything I can do other than specify a config file, which doesn't help as I don't know what setting is making it connect.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. I was told by the admin that I should use a different port than the default for RDP connections; turns out that port is used by VNC Server and thus the error (VNC and RDP don't speak the same language). I tried it from the command line without a port and it works fine, also works fine with the default 3389.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that some other application / program is using port 3389 ... 
Can you try to rdp from the same LAN?
I had a similar issue and the rdp port was assigned / occupied by another app.
Check for and uninstall the conflicting app or change the RDP port on your server. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759